# Windows OS-Sample example of Windows Firmware Update Driver

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, firmware

I have an Windows app exe file which updates the firmware of my usb device. For example: ./fwupdater.exe <fw.bin>

Since the above command requires manual upgrade by end user. I am planning to deliver firmware update by using windows firmware update driver.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/updating-device-firmware-using-windows-update

I could not find a reference example for same publicly.

How can I achieve this updating the firmware using windows driver.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your USB device is designed.

I would do it like that:

- on D0Entry invoke WorkItem.
- WorkItem will check version of the device and version of the file
- if there is mismatch and can update (depend on your configuration)
- Update the Device via USB Hardware function (depends on your endpoints and etc...)